# Using the new line character in conditionals

Tags: python

I am trying to use the newline character in a conditional statement.

The charater is in a list which was made from getting input using `sys.stdin.readline()`. Here's an example.

```
string=sys.stdin.readline()
input=list(string)
if (input[-1])=="/n":
    print "ok"
```

Why doesn't this work? If you print the list you see that `/n` is the last element in the list.

Comment: Newline is `\n`, not `/n`... Could that be the problem?

Comment: Because the escape char is `\n` - not a forward slash. Also - `readline` as shown will read until the next `\n` is found and it will  include that in your input - so it will always be the last char in your string... therefore it's a pointless check...

Comment: @JonClements: careful. :^)  Because of people doing things like `'\n'.join(whatever)`, it's often true that the last line doesn't have a trailing EOL marker.  Several of the online coding quizzes do this deliberately to mess with people.. (admittedly it's a little different here where we're reading from stdin, but it's still a dangerous habit..)

Comment: oh dear looks like that was the problem, that was just an example I wrote but I went through my actual program and that was the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DSM I guess it's possible that a file has been redirected to stdin...  (difficult and odd to not hit enter to enter a line for actual stdin :) otherwise)... I'll happily retract the *so it will always be the last char* as it may not be in the case you've mentioned :p. I still think it's a pointless check though :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it is caused by a simply typo/confusion of / and \ characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `'\n'` not `'/n'`. The escape character is a backslash in most languages.